# PHP MySQL Multiple Update

Tags: mysql, join

I have 2 tables that need updating based on 2 where clauses
i included a 3rd table which would join the other 2 tables together. i cant get either working.

```
UPDATE (list INNER JOIN Players ON list.Team_ID = Players.Players_Team_ID) INNER JOIN Users ON list.Team_ID = Users.User_Team_ID 
SET 
Players.Players_Team_ID = 6, Users.users_bank = users_bank-15000000, list.transfers = list.transfers+1
WHERE Users.User_ID=14 AND Players.Players_ID=3;
```

Without the 3rd table having an update it would be

```
UPDATE (list INNER JOIN Players ON list.Team_ID = Players.Players_Team_ID) INNER JOIN Users ON list.Team_ID = Users.User_Team_ID 
SET 
Players.Players_Team_ID = 6, Users.users_bank = users_bank-15000000
WHERE Users.User_ID=14 AND Players.Players_ID=3;
```

Can anyone help me get this working?

Answer (score 1):

You can change your query to be like below using `update-join` syntax but I don't see why you need to `JOIN` with other tables. Your `UPDATE` statements could be single or individual update as well

```
UPDATE list,Players,users
INNER JOIN Players ON list.Team_ID = Players.Players_Team_ID
INNER JOIN Users ON list.Team_ID = Users.User_Team_ID 
SET Players.Players_Team_ID = 6, 
Users.users_bank = users_bank - 15000000, 
list.transfers = list.transfers + 1
WHERE Users.User_ID=14 
AND Players.Players_ID=3;
```

Comment: UPDATE list,players,users
INNER JOIN players ON list.team_id = players.players_team_id
INNER JOIN users ON list.team_id = users.user_team_id 
SET players.players_team_id = 5, 
users.users_bank = users_bank - 200000
WHERE users.user_id=29 
AND players.players_id=2

MySQL said: Documentation
#1066 - Not unique table/alias: 'players'
This is what I am getting when i try it